# How to open Game Exporter with mel script?

Tags: maya, mel

I use [Game Exporter](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/Maya/files/GUID-2DB6E7B0-04B8-4585-91E9-7D64B02D0338-htm.html) to export my animation a lot. But I'm tired of selecting File > Game Exporter from the main menu.

Can I use mel script to open Game Exporter? Or even better, can I use the mel script to automatically generate the input for Game Exporter (For example: automatically input Export path, Animation name, Export selection only,...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I use mel script to open Game Exporter?

**Open game exporter**

```
gameFbxExporter;
```

> Or even better, can I use the mel script to automatically generate the
>   input for Game Exporter (For example: automatically input Export path,
>   Animation name, Export selection only,...)?

**Export path**

(Set to "E:/aaa")

```
setAttr -type "string" gameExporterPreset2.exportPath "E:/aaa";
```

**Animation name**

(Set to "aaa")

```
gameExp_SetUniqueAnimationClipName 0"aaa"gameExporterWindow|gameExporterTabFormLayout|gameExporterTabLayout|gameExporterAnimationTab|anim_gameExporterMainFormLayout|anim_gameExporterExportTypeFormLayout|formLayout344|anim_gameFbxExporterAnimClipFrameLayout|anim_gameFbxExporterAnimClipFormLayout|anim_gameFbxExporterScrollLayout|formLayout345|textField20;
```

But this is not really effective, because of the hard code: `formLayout344|`, `formLayout345|textField20`. Must find a way to make it dynamic.

So use this instead

```
setAttr -type "string" gameExporterPreset2.exportFilename "aaa";
```

**Export selection only**

```
setAttr("gameExporterPreset2.exportSetIndex") 2;
gameExp_CreateExportTypeUIComponents;
```

---

Here is how I figure it out: I check [all the records of Mel](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/troubleshooting/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2017/ENU/Maya/files/GUID-B0E70A37-1585-4FA1-99EF-D680A9152E18-htm.html).

Comment: If this works for you, you should mark the answer as correct so people coming along later can know that it solves the issue

Comment: Thank @theodox, but StackOverflow require at least 2 days before I can accept self-answer.

Comment: Regarding the dynamic animation clip name- I'm digging into this at the moment- using `setAttr  -type "string" "gameExporterPreset2.animClips[0].animClipName" "ThisIsTheFirstClip"` actually does set the clip name, but doesn't refresh the UI. Doing something like switching tabs refreshes the UI as expected, so it does look like the underlying data is updated as expected.

Answer (score 0):

to refresh to get the animation clip names to update

```
from maya import cmds
from maya import mel as mm

# setting the animation clip name, this is 0 indexed    
cmds.setAttr('gameExporterPreset2.animClips[0].animClipName', 'clipNameHere', type='string')

# For changes to Animation clip Name only we need to close and reopen the window
if cmds.window("gameExporterWindow", exists=True):
    print 'exists'
    cmds.deleteUI("gameExporterWindow")

else:
    pass

mm.eval('gameFbxExporter;')
```